# Issue with parsing HTML class elements using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

```
url = 'http://www.zillow.com/homedetails/3728-Balcary-Bay-Champaign-IL-61822/89057727_zpid/'
page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

info = soup.findAll('span',{'itemtype':'http://schema.org/GeoCoordinates'}) #this tag + class combination found 4 matches, 4th one was the required one, just selecting that here
for form in info:
        b= form.find('meta')['content']
print b
```

This is the snapshot of the code i am using to get the latitude and longitude information from Zillow. I can pin point the code where the latitude and longitude information is stored using span and itemtype. 
The place where I am parsing this data from has a code similar to the one below:

```
<span itemprop="geo" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/GeoCoordinates">
<meta content="40.12938" itemprop="latitude">
<meta content="-88.30766" itemprop="longitude">
</span>
```

I am able to get the latitude information but unable to get the longitude information. Can someone help me in getting this information?

Output of the code:

```
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
40.12938
>>>
```

Intended output:

```
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
40.12938 -88.30766
>>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `form.find()` finds the first result which is `<meta content="40.12938" itemprop="latitude">` but instead use the `form.find_all()` method to return all the results and then you can add them to a list using a list comprehension as depicted below:

```
url = 'http://www.zillow.com/homedetails/3728-Balcary-Bay-Champaign-IL-61822/89057727_zpid/'
page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

info = soup.findAll('span',{'itemtype':'http://schema.org/GeoCoordinates'}) #this tag + class combination found 4 matches, 4th one was the required one, just selecting that here
cordinates = [i['content'] for i in info[0].find_all('meta')]

print cordinates
```

it would produce:

```
[u'40.12938', u'-88.30766']
```